# Check datediff criteria between every value per user

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

Sample data:

```
id   rank   onboarded_at   applied_at   
A    1      1/1/2018       1/2/2018     
A    2      1/1/2018       2/3/2018     
A    3      1/1/2018       3/4/2018     
B    1      2/1/2018       null        
B    2      2/1/2018       8/1/2018     
C    1      3/1/2018       4/1/2018     
C    2      3/1/2018       7/1/2018     
C    3      3/1/2018       8/1/2018
```

I can calculate `lapsed_now` if there are >12 weeks (ie. 84 days) between: 1) `onboarded_at` and `current_date` (if no `applied_at` exists), 2) `max(applied_at)` and `current_date`.

It is calculated like so:

```
case when max(applied_at) over (partition by id) is null and current_date - 84 > onboarded_at::date then 1
when current_date - 84 > max(applied_at) over (partition by id)::date and onboarded_at < max(applied_at) over (partition by id) then 1 else 0 end lapsed_now
```

Output:

```
id   rank   onboarded_at   applied_at   lapsed_now
A    1      1/1/2018       1/2/2018     1
A    2      1/1/2018       2/3/2018     1
A    3      1/1/2018       3/4/2018     1 
B    1      2/1/2018       null         0
B    2      2/1/2018       8/1/2018     0 --not lapsed now
C    1      3/1/2018       4/1/2018     0
C    2      3/1/2018       7/1/2018     0
C    3      3/1/2018       8/1/2018     0 --not lapsed now
```

However, I would like to similarly calculate an `id` level `lapsed_ever` column, where we add these 2 additional conditions to lapsed_now:

1) If it took >84 days to get first `applied_at` (no matter if there is an `applied_at`within 84 days later)

2) If it took >84 between ANY of `applied_at` for the id (each applied has rank +1)

How can I do it? This would be the output- where B is `lapsed_ever` because of how long it took to get first `applied_at` and C is `lapsed_ever` because of how long it took to get from `rank=1` to `rank=2`:

```
id   rank   onboarded_at   applied_at   lapsed_now   lapsed_ever
A    1      1/1/2018       1/2/2018     1            0           
A    2      1/1/2018       2/3/2018     1            0
A    3      1/1/2018       3/4/2018     1            0
B    1      2/1/2018       null         0            1 --lapsed
B    2      2/1/2018       8/1/2018     0            1
C    1      3/1/2018       4/1/2018     0            1
C    2      3/1/2018       8/1/2018     0            1 --lapsed
C    3      3/1/2018       9/1/2018     0            1
```

For condition #1 I think I can do:
`case when datediff(day, onboarded_at, min(applied_at) over (partition by id))>84 then 1`
But not sure what to do for #2

----EDIT----
As per @Jim's answer, it looks like this is my output:

```
id  rank    onboarded_at    applied_at  lapsed_now  lapsed_date
A   1       1/1/2018        1/2/2018    1           (null)
A   2       1/1/2018        2/3/2018    1           (null)
A   3       1/1/2018        3/4/2018    1           (null)
B   1       2/1/2018        (null)      0           10/24/2018 
B   2       2/1/2018        8/1/2018    0           10/24/2018 
C   1       3/1/2018        4/1/2018    0           11/24/2018 
C   2       3/1/2018        8/1/2018    0           11/24/2018 
C   3       3/1/2018        9/1/2018    0           11/24/2018
```

However, it should be:

```
id  rank    onboarded_at    applied_at  lapsed_now  lapsed_date
A   1       1/1/2018        1/2/2018    1           5/27/2018
A   2       1/1/2018        2/3/2018    1           5/27/2018
A   3       1/1/2018        3/4/2018    1           5/27/2018 (March 4 + 84)
B   1       2/1/2018        (null)      0           4/26/2018 (Feb 1 + 84)
B   2       2/1/2018        8/1/2018    0           4/26/2018
C   1       3/1/2018        4/1/2018    0           6/24/2018 
C   2       3/1/2018        8/1/2018    0           6/24/2018 (Apr 1 + 84)
C   3       3/1/2018        9/1/2018    0           6/24/2018
```

Comment: What's the date format here? Is it mm/DD/yyyy?

Comment: @JimJimson yes it is

Comment: You'll need another case statement. If it's elapsed now then use onboarded + 84, otherwise use the existing.

Comment: Do you mind updating your solution to reflect the correct answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like the two cases you mentioned are effectively the same. You want to know if 84 days ever elapsed for each id. You can do that with the below:

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.Onboarded
(
  id VARCHAR(10),
  rank INTEGER,
  onboarded_at DATE,
  applied_at DATE
  );

INSERT INTO dbo.Onboarded VALUES
('A',1,'20180101','20180102'),
('A',2,'20180101','20180203'),
('A',3,'20180101','20180304'),
('B',1,'20180201',NULL),
('B',2,'20180201','20180801'),
('C',1,'20180301','20180401'),
('C',2,'20180301','20180801'),
('C',3,'20180301','20180901');

SELECT onb.[id],
onb.[rank],
onb.[onboarded_at],
onb.[applied_at],
onb.[lapsed_now],
CASE WHEN [lapsed_now] = 1 OR [lapsed_previous] = 1
    THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END [lapsed_ever],
CASE WHEN lapsed_now = 1
    THEN DATEADD(DAY, 84, [lapsed_now_date])
    ELSE [min_applied_at_add_84]
END [lapsed_date]
FROM
(SELECT *,
CASE
    WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, onboarded_at, MIN(ISNULL(applied_at, onboarded_at)) over (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY rank ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)) >= 84
        THEN 1
    WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, MAX(applied_at) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY rank ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING), GETDATE()) >= 84
        THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END [lapsed_now],
CASE
    WHEN MAX(DATEDIFF(DAY, onboarded_at, ISNULL(applied_at, GETDATE()))) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY rank ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) >= 84
        THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END [lapsed_previous],
MAX(applied_at) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY rank ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) [lapsed_now_date],
DATEADD(DAY, 84, MIN(CASE WHEN applied_at IS NULL THEN onboarded_at ELSE applied_at END) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY rank ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)) [min_applied_at_add_84]
FROM dbo.Onboarded
) onb
```

Results:

```
id  rank    onboarded_at    applied_at  lapsed_now  lapsed_ever lapsed_date
A   1       2018-01-01      2018-01-02  1           1           2018-05-27
A   2       2018-01-01      2018-02-03  1           1           2018-05-27
A   3       2018-01-01      2018-03-04  1           1           2018-05-27
B   1       2018-02-01      (null)      0           1           2018-04-26
B   2       2018-02-01      2018-08-01  0           1           2018-04-26
C   1       2018-03-01      2018-04-01  0           1           2018-06-24
C   2       2018-03-01      2018-08-01  0           1           2018-06-24
C   3       2018-03-01      2018-09-01  0           1           2018-06-24
```

The key is ensuring that your window function pays attention to all rows in each window, which is where the ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING comes in.

You can read more about how to use them [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_Window_function_synopsis.html).

Comment: Thanks @Jim - as mentioned this is for Redshift, so let me try to re-write it and test

Comment: Ah, apologies. It looks fairly similar according to this: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_Window_function_synopsis.html

Comment: Certainly is! I think I just need to replace iif with case when

Comment: Question, how would I add date lapsed (max)? `... then coalesce(applied_at + 84,  onboarded_at + 84) else null`?

Comment: Great what I thought. It says I need to wait 20 hours to award the bounty but will do when I can :)

Comment: Great, happy to help.

Comment: I realized this doesnt work. ID A is lapsed now- but your query shows him as not lapsed ever. Also lapsed date returns max(applied_at)+84 which isn't correct. Lastly, if I only do Over (Partition By id) I get the same result as using "ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING". Edited the problem description with details

Comment: I've updated my answer for you. And I've included all of the columns and shown you how to make the final result in lapsed_date.

Comment: Unfortunately it still isn't right: 1) lapsed_ever=1 for all 3 IDs, but your input has lapsed_ever=0 for ID A. 2) lapsed_date for ID=C should be 6/24 since he lapsed on April 1 not March 1 (he onboarded a client within a month between March and April, but didnt onbboard a client for 4 months between April and August)

Comment: Have updated once more. The results should line up with what you're expecting.

Comment: Ah. sorry but still incorrect :( It looks like youre taking min date for date_lapsed but for ID A it should be based on March 4 + 84, not Jan 2. Also, 
 if for ID 3 rank 2 we change applied_at to 5/1, then the lapsed_date will return 6/24 based on 4/1 applied_at, instead of 7/24. Since bounty expires in 9 hours and it is nighttime here- Ill award it now. Hope you can correct it one last time to account for all the scenarios

Comment: Great, thanks. I'll have a look tonight and make the required changes.

Comment: I've updated that now so that for A the lapsed_date is 3/Mar/2018 + 84 days = 27/May/2018. Lapsed Dates are as follows: A) 27/May/2018, B) 26/Apr/2018, C) 26/Jun/2018. Is that what they're supposed to be? You mention C should show 24/Jul, why is that? Neither the 1/Apr nor the 1/May are more than 84 days after the onboarded_at date, or do you want to show the max date before it was elapsed for the final time?

Comment: May 27 for A is correct, sorry miscalculated the addition lol. June 24 for C is correct however I am saying if we alter the table to have ID 3 rank 2 applied_at of 5/1, we need the returned value to be July 24 (May 1+84,  Apr 1 no longer lapsed since takes 1 month until next applied_at)- and based on the query I am getting min applied_at+84 ie. June 24.

Comment: So it's the difference between the applied_at values of each row that determines whether the row has lapsed or not?

Comment: lapsed_date is when there are >12 weeks (ie. 84 days) between: 1) onboarded_at and current_date (if no applied_at exists), 2) onboarded_at and min(applied_at) (if one exists), 3) each consecutive applied_at, 4) max(applied_at) and current_date. If there are multiple instances where he lapsed, then we show the max lapsed date

Comment: You actually did get me to the output I wanted so technically this question is answered, it just doesnt hold if I change sample data. I will create a separate question for this

Comment: I know how to get the answer you want, you need to use LAG to get the date difference between the applied_at dates, and then use a MAX over the top of that. I'm in transit at the moment though, so won't be able to help until tomorrow probably..

Comment: I'll be waiting patiently :) Thank you

Comment: Actually, just having another look at this now and I'm in the dark. It would be worth posting a new question with a full set of test data that outlines all of your situations. Also, you should include test cases where there are multiple different lapsed cases going on for the same id and point out the correct one.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52501443/create-a-lapsed-concept-based-on-logic-across-every-row-per-id